# Retrieve each data on css lightbox with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, codeigniter, lightbox

I’m new in [Codeigniter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeIgniter_(framework)), and I’m facing problem to retrieve individual id in to light-box.

First of all I want to retrieve all my data in my view page with the name. and then I want to show details information of a user with a light-box by clicking that **name** link without page refreshing. Mean I want on page data rendering.

Here is my Controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
 $this->load->model('model','',TRUE);           
 $this->load->view('header');
        $data['query'] = $this->model->retrieve_data();
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
    public function retrieve_one()
    {
        $data['data'] = $this->model->retrieve_row();
        $this->load->view('result', $data); 
    }
```

I'm confusing about my model and  want to know is there any way to retrieve data in lightbox from model?

Here is my Model:

```
class model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function retrieve_data()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('cidata');
        return $query->result();
    }
    public function retrieve_row()
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(2));
        $data= $this->db->get('cidata');
        return $data->result();
    }
```

**And Finally here is my View:**

 is it possible to use jquery for getting data?

```
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>

<?php echo(anchor("#lights/$row->id", "$row->name<br><br>", "onclick=lighton()")); ?>


<div id="lights">

    <?php echo($row->name); ?>

<p><a id="exit" onclick=lightoff(); href="javascript:void(0);">X</a></p></div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Note: if I put light-box into foreach its render only first id and if I put light-box out side of  foreach its render only my last id.

JavaScript for light box:

```
function lighton()
{
    document.getElementById("lights").style.display="block";
}
function lightoff()
{
    document.getElementById('lights').style.display='none';
}
```

All of the code rendering my user’s list on my view page. But light-box not getting     individual id to render individual user informations.

Note: Here if I use anchor like:

```
<?php echo(anchor("welcome/retrieve_one/$row->id", "$row->name<br><br>", "onclick=lighton()")); ?>
```

Its render perfectly into result page, but I don’t want that because it goes another     page with id. I want on page data render with light-box. How to solve? Please!

Comment: yes it wont work because you are creating multiple div with same id `lights` so it work for only first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class to anchor and use hide show. See below example

```
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>

<?php echo(anchor("#lights/$row->id", "$row->name<br><br>", array('class'=>'lights_on'))); ?>


 <div class="lights">

    <?php echo($row->name); ?>

   <p><a class="exit" href="javascript:void(0);">X</a></p>
</div>
```

```
$('.lights_on').click(function(){
    $(this).next().show();
});

$('.exit').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
})
```